# Chaotic and Ordered Random Boolean Newtorks with a fixed in-degree k and a probability p

Tags: information, non-linear-systems, stochastic-processes, complex-systems, randomness

I'm working with Random Boolean Networks, I made a python program to show the dynamics of the networks. Before coding the program I study the theory and it says that the in-degree *k* and the probability *p* of gettin 1 over 0 determines the phase of the RBN.
Here is the condition:

For chaotic regime $$k\cdot2p(1-p)<1$$

For ordered regime $$k\cdot2p(1-p)>1$$

For at the edge of chaos regime $$ k \cdot 2p(1-p)=1$$

[image]

I made the network with k = 5 and p = 0.8, but sometimes I get ordered networks instead of getting chaotic networks as conditions dictate. I dont know if I´m not understanding well the theory, somebody could explain me please?
Thanks

Here is the code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import itertools
from itertools import product
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_conecciones_nodos = 5
num_nodos=20

# Initial States of the 20 nodes (ON/OFF) (1/0) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nodos=[]
for i in range(num_nodos):
    k = random.randint(0, 1)
    nodos.append(k)
#print("Estado Inicial de los nodos")
#print(nodos)
#print("")

#This is all the possible connections that every node can have with another 5 nodes--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(['0','1'], repeat = num_conecciones_nodos)]
#print(keywords)


#This is the truth table of the boolean functions, the probability p of getting 1 es 0.8 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Valfunciones = []
l = 2**(num_conecciones_nodos)
sampleList = [0,1]
for i in range(l):
    z = random.choices(
    sampleList, weights=(20,80), k=1)
    Valfunciones.append(z[0])

#print("Tabla de Verdad / Valores de las Funciones booleanas")
#print(Valfunciones)
#print(" ")


#This is to make randomly the connections of every node ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
conecciones = np.zeros((20,5))
for i in range(20):
    nums = random.sample(range(1, 20), 5)
    conecciones[i] = [nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3], nums[4]]
#print("Conecciones de cada nodo")
#print(conecciones)

#This is the method that make the connections of every node with another 5 nodes --------------------------------------------
valorconecciones = [0] * 20
for i in range(20):
    valorconecciones[i] = str(nodos[int(conecciones[i][0] - 1)]) + str(nodos[int(conecciones[i][1] - 1)]) + \
                          str(nodos[int(conecciones[i][2] - 1)]) + str(nodos[int(conecciones[i][3] - 1)]) + \
                          str(nodos[int(conecciones[i][4] - 1)])
print("")
print("Valor de las conecciones en base a los nodos conectados y a las funciones booleanas")
print(valorconecciones)


matriz = np.zeros((200,20))

#This is the method that updates the state of the 20 nodes following the boolean functions --------------------------------------------
for z in range(200):

    #print(nodos)
    matriz[z] = nodos
    for x in range(num_nodos):
        valorconecciones[x] = str(nodos[int(conecciones[x][0] - 1)]) + str(nodos[int(conecciones[x][1] - 1)]) + \
                              str(nodos[int(conecciones[x][2] - 1)]) + str(nodos[int(conecciones[x][3] - 1)]) + \
                              str(nodos[int(conecciones[x][4] - 1)])
    for i in range(num_nodos):
        for j in range(32):
            if valorconecciones[i] == keywords[j]:
                nodos[i] = Valfunciones[j]

plt.imshow(matriz,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```